# android passing id from database to arraylist

Tags: android, database, listview

i am doing a listview and getting data from database .. each view or row has its value from the database

but how to pass the id also from the database to the list view

so when i click one one view i get the id and do my thing like (delete ... where id = ...)

[this how it looks](http://postimg.org/image/cdcy16f8p/)

this is my code  thank you :

```
private void setAdapter() {


dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
Cursor c = dbHelper.getcursor("M_table","M_title");
String s="";
Integer i=0;
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
if (c != null ) {
if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
do {
i++;
int Mid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Mid"));
String M_title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("M_title"));






values.add(M_title);  



}while (c.moveToNext());
}
}


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,values);

setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Write a custom listadapter. Here is a good tutorial. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

first of all in you'll have to store the id in your listview XML file.have a field like this followed by your other fields.

`<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />`

then in your adapter code,you will have to retrieve the id from this field and pass it to the next activity using a bundle.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String clickid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Id))
                    .getText().toString();

            Bundle job_info = new Bundle();
            id_info.putString("key", clickid);
            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(id_info);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```